# DropdownList SqlDataSource does not pull *all* records

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

I have a DropDownList which is tied to SQLDataSource. I am running the exact same query in SQL Management studio and it pulls all the records but when I execute it in SQLDataSource, it does not pull the two records that I just added. Why?

```
SELECT [RepID], [ManagerID] 
FROM MyDB1.dbo.Reps 
WHERE [Role] = 'Manager' AND ISNULL(RepType, 'Account Exec') <> 'House Account Exec'

union

SELECT [RepID], [ManagerID] 
FROM MyDB2.dbo.Reps 
WHERE [Role] = 'Manager' AND ISNULL(RepType, 'Account Exec') <> 'House Account Exec'
```

The problem line seems to be RepType field. I did verify it it is *NULL* for the records that I want to pull. I have spend more than an hour on it. Anyone come across such a thing? Any suggestions?

Output from SMSS

```
RepID       ManagerID
----------- -----------
1           1
9           9
10          10        <- this guy does not show in DropDown
42          42
333         333       <- and this guy
1026        1026
1065        1065
2014        1
3009        3009
3025        3025
5000        5000
5002        5002
6000        6000
9000        9000
```

this is not the only problem. Even if remove the ISNULL(RepType, 'Account Exec') condition, it still does not pull the repID=333, while it does pul repID=10.

What I found is that there is a duplicate of repID =10 but still it should behave the same way in SSMS and in dropdownlist.

Comment: yes, database names are tied to the table names [database1].dbo.reps

Comment: Can you post the results/output in text/screenshot of the above query from SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour should not be like this. This is probably a bug but what I have found so far

1. Rep with RepID=10 exhisted for two records, that could be a problem.
2. In the two tables, one table has reptype='House Account Exec', while in other it is Null. This condition in interprted differently when the query is executed in SMSS and in SQLDatasource.

There are still things that I can not resolve. For example repID=333, appears in SMSS but not dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest converting your SQL query into a stored procedure instead of your adhoc SQL statement.